# Google sheets script - Unable to get background color from cells that are part of pivot table

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have written the following code which replicates a Google Sheets pivot table in HTML along with the formatting to send out in an email.

issue: getBackgrounds() does not return the colours of the cells of the pivot table (it always returns #FFFFF). I verified the range to be correct, because the table is rendered with the correct amount of rows and columns along with the data values. However without styling. Further, if the colour of a cell is changed manually in the Sheets UI before running the script, then getBackgrounds() will fetch that colour. How can I retrieve the formatting of the pivot table?

code:

```
function getData(){
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("TCD").getRange(5,1).getDataRegion();
  let background = ss.getBackgrounds();
  let val = ss.getDisplayValues();
  let fontColor = ss.getFontColors();
  let fontStyles = ss.getFontStyles();
  let fontWeight = ss.getFontWeights();
  let fontSize = ss.getFontSizes();
  return [val,background,fontColor,fontStyles,fontWeight,fontSize];
}

function setupEmail(attachment, sendBool) {
  let ss_data = getData();
  let data = ss_data[0];
  let background = ss_data[1];
  let fontColor = ss_data[2];
  let fontStyles = ss_data[3];
  let fontWeight = ss_data[4];
  let fontSize = ss_data[5];

  html += "<table border='1' style=\"background-color:#000000;\">"; 
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      html += "<tr>" 
      for (let j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) { 
          html += "<td style=\"height:20px;background-color:" + background[i][j] + "; color: " + fontColor[i][j] + "; font-style: " + fontStyles[i][j] + "; font-weight: " + fontWeight[i][j] + "; font-size: " + (fontSize[i][j] + 6) + "px; text-align: center;\">" + data[i][j] + "</td>";
          Logger.log(background[i][j]);
      }
      html += "</tr>";
  }
  html + "</table>"
```

EDIT: I have worked around this by hardcoding the background-color. If anyone knows why the background colors of a pivot table cannot be returned, please do contribute.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine your Spreadsheet from your question. So, in order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet? And, also can you provide your expected output? By this, I would like to try to understand your question.

Comment: @Tanaike No worries. I do apologize as i cannot provide the spreadsheet due to sensitive export controlled material. You can picture it as a pivot table which extracts data from a sheet. I then want to send this pivot table in an email. The code above converts the pivot table to an HTML table which I include as htmlBody in sendEmail(). The output would be the HTML table with the same formatting as the pivot table in Sheets. My issue is that .getbackgrounds() do not work on the pivot table, i.e. it does not return the color codes of the cells of the pivot table

Comment: @Tanaike You can replicate this easily by creating a pivot table and then trying getBackgrounds() on that range. It will not return the background colour codes corresponding to the cells of the pivot table

Comment: Thank you for replying. I understood about `I do apologize as i cannot provide the spreadsheet due to sensitive export controlled material.`. But, unfortunately, from your replying, I cannot still understand your question. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. But, I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand your question, I would like to think of the solution.